# Link to the object in the letter

Tags: django, email, django-templates

I have `url:path('<int:id>',views.article_detail,name="detail")`
It works on the site.

```
 <p><a href="{% url 'detail' id=article.id %}">{{article.title}}</a> </p>
```

But if I try to give a link in the email, for example

```
   <p><a href="{% url 'detail' id=article.id %}">article </a></p>
```

In link I heve only

> http://articles/36

Link like

```
<p><a href="127.0.0.1:8000+{% url 'detail' id=article.id %}">artickle! </a></p>
```

not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to accomplish what you need.

If it’s just one time work then I suggest something quick:

On your view import the settings and send to the template the ‘settings.BASE_URL’ value

```
from django.conf import settings
base_url = settings.BASE_URL
```

you can pass the value in your context to create the url as you already tried to do.

Another option is to create a tag to get the base url from the setting and generate the complete url base on the given parameter

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

base_url = settings.BASE_URL
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
 def add_domain(partial_url):
      return base_url + partial_url
```

In your template just use

```
{% add_domain url_generated %}
```

This is just an example, you could define a more complex tag to generate the url included the domain with a flag parameter.